# Like Condition to get rdfs:label using Spark query

Tags: java, apache-spark, jena, ontology

I am using this query to get specific class in an ontology using jena and spark.

```
 final String queryString = "" +
            "prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "select ?class where {\n" +
            "  ?class rdfs:label \""+ word +"\"\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "";
ResultSet results = QueryExecutionFactory.create( queryString, model).execSelect();
```

how should I change the query to get classes that word is part of their labels?
actually I need something like "sql Like statement" in spark.
thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not Spark it is Sparql, for apache spark head [here](http://spark.apache.org/). What you are looking for is the String functions. You might be looking for the regex() function. But anything else than the most trivial queries will take a lot of time, in fact it is advisable to not use like in any DB system. Your SPARQL string should be like :

```
final String queryString =
        "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
        "SELECT ?s ?label ?contains" 
        "WHERE {" +
        "   ?s rdfs:label ?label ." +
        "   BIND(CONTAINS(?label,\""+ variableToFind +"\") AS ?contains)"
        "}";
```

Also you are not searching for a class you are looking for a subject and that can be a URI, BN, literal.

Comment: yes.you are right.it takes a lot of time .but how can I search in a shorter time?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to highlight the string function, use CONTAINS it is a little faster but without an inverted index it would be slow, use Lucene or use the [Jena default implementation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html).

Answer (score 0):

after more search I Found right query

```
String Quert ="PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"
            + " SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x rdfs:label ?v ." +
            "FILTER regex(?v, \"word\", \"i\")}" ;
```